# asp:RegularExpressionValidator error message do not hide when value is possible

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, webforms

I am using `RegularExpressionValidator` in an asp form to validate a persian date. The first time the user enters a wrong value, the errormessage appears. Consider that the user edits her/his entry correctly and continues to the next field, this time the errormessage is still shown. How to resolve this problem?

My code is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLicenseDate" runat="server" CssClass="labelclass" Width="60px" MaxLength="8" onclick="showCal('calFirstDate'); return false;" Style="text-align: left" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDate" runat="server" CssClass="labelclass" Forelor="#DD3509" ControlToValidate="txtLicenseDate" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="date is wrong" validationExpression="\d{2}/(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)/(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|1\d{1}|2d{1}|30|31)">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: wet in my language is a idiom for weak ! :p

Comment: already deleted brother :)

Comment: ok jigar ,,, jigar means baby or hny ;)

Comment: lol ur definitely Indian :)) oh u edited in my language jigar means close friend

Comment: my language is persian